# MongoDB issue with mongoimport of string autoconverting to number

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoimport

I have a tsv (tab delimited file) with some contact information I want to load into a mongo collection. So I am using mongoimport (which I have to use for reasons I will not go into here, so please don't recommend another way of importing).

I have the telephone number defined as an array by having "telephone.0" in the header line (--headerline).

I use the following command to import the data:

`$ mongoimport --db=dbname --collection=colname --type=tsv --headerline --file=datafile.tsv`

or

`$ mongoimport --db=dbname --collection=colname --type=tsv --headerline --useArrayIndexFields --file=datafile.tsv`

I tried both without and with --useArrayIndexFields.

When the telephone number contains special characters like +1 (44) 1234 1234 it reads it in as a string (the way I want it to be read in), but when the telephone number is only a number like 8881112222 it converts it to a NumberLong("8881112222"). If that telephone number would have been 888-111-2222 it would have saved it as a string in the array.

```
"telephone" : [
   NumberLong("8881112222")
]
```

versus

```
"telephone" : {
   "0" : "888-111-2222"
}
```

HOW can I tell it to EXPLICITLY save the telephone number as a STRING regardless of the data?
Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: You can specify the type of each field in the `fields` option.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the syntax please?

Comment: This is from the manual: [Import CSV with Specified Field Types](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/#import-csv-with-specified-field-types)

Comment: If I use the fields file and define a field as an array, example: telephone.array(), how can I specify the type of array, telephone.array(string) ???

Comment: I dont think array data type is supported. But, you can import a string and and update it to any other format once the data is in the database - that would be another process.